# Why does averagePowerForChannel always return -160?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have these code and both method call are SUCCESS.

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: NULL];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: NULL];
```

And these code to start recording:

```
[self.recorder prepareToRecord];
[self.recorder recordForDuration: 60];
```

I have a timer function to update meters

```
- (void)updateMeters
{
    [self.recorder updateMeters];
    float peakPower = [self.recorder averagePowerForChannel: 0];
    double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (ALPHA * peakPower));
    self.recordView.progress = peakPowerForChannel;

    NSLog(@"%f", peakPower);
}
```

But I do not know why peakPower is always 160. I have another demo(from web) can work well, but I can not find any difference between them.

Comment: Similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022514/avaudiorecorder-averagepowerforchannel-always-returns-120-0

Comment: self.recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that `[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &err]` and `[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: self.recordPath] settings: recordSetting error: NULL]` must in the same function...It is the answer of this question.

Answer (score 4):

Just try to set:

```
   recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and check

```
NSError *error;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] 
    setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error description: %@", [error description]);
}
```

Comment: It is success. I have already added these code in my project(before I ask this question).