# Why is my update() function not reacting on dB levels?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to make my app react to claps or higher than normal sound levels. I'm using Swift and SpriteKit for this. I have imported AVFoundation and of course SpriteKit. This is my setup:

```
let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
.UserDomainMask, true)

let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

let soundFilePath =
docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")

let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)

let recordSettings =
[AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Min.rawValue,
AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0]

let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Apple_Swift_Logo")
let recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject], error: nil)
var impulseAdded = false
```

I got this code from [this site](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_iOS_8_with_AVAudioRecorder_in_Swift).

Next inside `GameScene` and `didMoveToView()`:

```
//sprite
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(320, 568)
    addChild(sprite)

//recorder; meteringEnabled set to true to allow access to dB levels
    recorder.meteringEnabled = true
    recorder.record()
```

And finally inside the `update()` function:

```
recorder.updateMeters()
 if recorder.averagePowerForChannel(1) > -160 && impulseAdded == false {
    sprite.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 100))
    impulseAdded = true
}
```

The sprite remains static. No impulse is applied. What's my problem here?

References:

- [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html)
- [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioRecorder/url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to this line of code:

```
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1
```

It's in the `recordSettings`.

Then in the `update()` function this `if recorder.averagePowerForChannel(1) > -160`
has to be changed to this:

```
if recorder.averagePowerForChannel(0) > -160
```

It seems to be working like an array, it starts at zero.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking for any recording errors ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991908/why-does-averagepowerforchannel-always-return-160)).

```
var error : NSError?
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error:&error)

if let anError = error {
    NSLog("Error description: \(anError)")
}
```

or in your case

```
var error : NSError?
let recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject], error: &error)
if let anError = error {
    NSLog("Error description: \(anError)")
}
```

and

```
var success = recorder.record()
NSLog("recorded successfully? \(success)")
```

Comment: I tried it that way and a similar way where I println() the status of recorder.recording. It returned true. When it comes to errors I never get any.

Comment: Asking the OP to check for errors does not answer the question. This should be a comment.

Comment: @ecoguy kk, seems like you found the issue channel array. surprised the error wasn't more helpful like "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Comment: Yeah,I expected Xcode to tell me about such issues. Like "no record settings for chosen channel". Glad the problem is solved :)