# Getting Decibels from AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to get a decibel value from an AVAudio Recorder. This is my code currently. I have a method to start the recorder, then a method to read the decibel values.

```
    var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
```

Recorder defined globally, then used here:

```
    func init_recorder() -> Void
{
    let recordersettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatAppleIMA4),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1 as NSNumber,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
        //AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue
    ]
    let filename = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingString("tmp.caf"))

    do
    {
        recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: filename, settings: recordersettings)
        recorder.meteringEnabled = true
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        recorder.record()
        recorder.updateMeters()

    }
    catch
    {
        print("error")
    }


}
```

Then to get the decibel values I have

```
    func get_decibels() -> Float
{
    recorder.updateMeters()
    return recorder.averagePowerForChannel(0)
}
```

For some reason this is returning a value of -120.0 every time it is called and i'm not too sure why. I have read from http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-decibels-from-the-ios-microphone/ and a few other stack overflow threads but most of the examples seem to be quite similar to mine.

Any help appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVAudioRecorder averagePowerForChannel always returns -120.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022514/avaudiorecorder-averagepowerforchannel-always-returns-120-0)

Answer (score 1):

After you have inited the AVAudioSession

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    try session.setActive(true)
try recorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: getDocumentsDirectory(), settings: settings)
```

and started recorder

```
func start() {
    recorder?.record()
    recorder?.updateMeters()
}
```

You can get the decibels by calling

```
let decibels = recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
```

from -120 (min value) up to 0. Noice level of some cafe for example is -20

here's the more detailed example http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/04/15/swift-how-to-get-decibels/

Comment: The link goes to a scam site at the moment :/