# Find silence in AVAudioRecorder Session

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

How can I stop the audio recording once the user stops taking? 
Like Siri. Once you say, Hi Siri it will respond to your voice. Means Siri app listening to the audio until you stop the taking.

I'm trying to do the same thing. If I say, **Get weather details** once I stop my voice. I want to trigger one method or call the API with recorded audio till is stop.

My requirement is app should continuously listen to the user find the voice end event send data to the server or just trigger a method.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreAudio
import CoreAudioKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import AVKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    private var recorder    : AVAudioRecorder? = nil
    private var isRecording : Bool = false
    private var timer       : Timer? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        permissionWasGranted { (isValied) in
            print("isValied")
            self.isRecording = false;
            self.intiateTimer()

        }
    }

    @objc func intiateTimer() {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    @objc func updateTimer() {

        if !isRecording {
            //recorder = nil
            self.initRecorder()
            print("Recording intiated")
        }
        else {
            print("Recording Started")
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let fileManager         = FileManager.default
        let urls                = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory   = urls.first!
        return documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
    }

    // MARK: protocol


    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        recorder.stop()
        recorder.deleteRecording()
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        isRecording = false
        self.updateTimer()
    }


    func permissionWasGranted(result: @escaping (_: Bool)->()) {
        switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
            //if IS_DEBUG { print("Permission granted") }
            print("Permission granted")

            result(true)
            return
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
            //if IS_DEBUG { print("Pemission denied") }
                print("Pemission denied")
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
            //if IS_DEBUG { print("Request permission here") }
            print("Request permission here")

            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
                if granted {
                    result(true)
                    return
                }
            })

        }
        result(false)
    }

    func initRecorder() {
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
        do {
            let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
            try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
            try session.setActive(true)

            try recorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: getDocumentsDirectory(), settings: settings)
            recorder!.delegate = self
            recorder!.isMeteringEnabled = true

            if !recorder!.prepareToRecord() {
                print("Error: AVAudioRecorder prepareToRecord failed")
            }


            let decibels = self.getDispersyPercent()
            if decibels > -120  && decibels < -20 {
                self.timer?.invalidate()
                isRecording = true;
                self.start()
            }


        } catch {
            print("Error: AVAudioRecorder creation failed")
        }
    }

    func start() {
        recorder?.record()
        recorder?.updateMeters()
    }

    func update() {
        if let recorder = recorder {
            recorder.updateMeters()
        }
    }

    func getDispersyPercent() -> Float {
        if let recorder = recorder {
            let decibels = recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
            return decibels
        }
        return 0
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to track the decibel(db) of the recorder

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43429136/468724 . Remember that you need to fire timer to get the value after specific interval

Comment: You can go with speech synthesyer available in iOS sdk. it will convert your voice into text immediately. For demo https://github.com/Gagan5278/SpeechSynthesizer

Comment: I have added my code here, Can anyone help me. Where I'm missing?

Comment: @Damodar did you find any solutions on this. Me too facing the same issue and I tried with some trimming techniques(AVAssetExportSession) but still not getting proper output. I need to reset the AVAudioRecorder if user remains silence for particular time period. Is it possible kindly let me know if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here I Have created my function that will actually detect silence for 5 seconds and if condition is satisfied you can stop recording that time

-- I had used Recording Manager NSObject class so you can get the code from below function and manage to use it in yours

Code

```
//StartNewRecordingIfSilenceFor5Second
    func newSessionIfSilence(){

        //get Audio file name to store
        let AudioFileName = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(getUniqueName()).wav")
        //Declare a value that will be updated when silence is detected
        var statusForDetection = Float()
        //Recorder Settings used
        let settings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
            AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue,
            AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
            ]
        //Try block
        do {
            //Start Recording With Audio File name
            Manager.recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: AudioFileName, settings: settings)
            Manager.recorder?.delegate = self
            Manager.recorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
            Manager.recorder?.prepareToRecord()
            Manager.recorder?.record()

            //Tracking Metering values here only
            Manager.meterTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.10, repeats: true, block: { (timer: Timer) in

                //Update Recording Meter Values so we can track voice loudness
                //Getting Recorder from another class
                //i managed my recorder from Manager class
                if let recorder = Manager.recorder
                {
                    //Start Metering Updates
                    recorder.updateMeters()

                    //Get peak values
                    Manager.recorderApc0 = recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
                    Manager.recorderPeak0 = recorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0)

                    //it’s converted to a 0-1 scale, where zero is complete quiet and one is full volume.
                    let ALPHA: Double = 0.05
                    let peakPowerForChannel = pow(Double(10), (0.05 * Double(Manager.recorderPeak0)))

//                    static var lowPassResults: Double = 0.0
                    RecordingManager.lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * RecordingManager.lowPassResults

                    if(RecordingManager.lowPassResults > 0){
                        print("Mic blow detected")
                        //Do what you wanted to do here

                        //if blow is detected update silence value as zero
                        statusForDetection = 0.0
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //Update Value for Status is blow being detected or not
                        //As timer is called at interval of 0.10 i.e 0.1 So add value each time in silence Value with 0.1
                        statusForDetection += 0.1


                        //if blow is not Detected for 5 seconds
                        if statusForDetection > 5.0 {
                            //Update value to zero
                            //When value of silence is greater than 5 Seconds
                            //Time to Stop recording
                            statusForDetection = 0.0

                            //Stop Audio recording
                            recorder.stop()

                        }
                    }
                }
            })

        } catch {
            //Finish Recording with a Error
            print("Error Handling: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.finishRecording(success: false)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your calculation for lowPassResults is a little bit confusing. Checking average power value (e.g., if recorderApc0 < -40 for silence) is less confusing way of doing same thing.

Comment: Yes it is I actually get it converted to scale of 0 to 1

Comment: Doesn't this create an indefinite number of .wav files?

Comment: Depend on silence "statusForDetection" I seted to 5.0 after each 5 second of audio recording it will create new file

Answer (score 1):

You can add a periodic listener to the recorder (after start recording), and check `recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)` you can handle the minimum level to stop recording.

Comment: You have to take care with this, I don't know if you know. 0 value is the maximum

**Return Value
The current average power, in decibels, for the sound being recorded. A return value of 0 dB indicates full scale, or maximum power; a return value of -160 dB indicates minimum power (that is, near silence).
If the signal provided to the audio recorder exceeds ±full scale, then the return value may exceed 0 (that is, it may enter the positive range).**

[link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder/1387176-averagepower)